# Is the center tag still valid?

Tags: html, tags, center

I mostly use the HTML `<center>` tag to center most of my objects. I just wanted to confirm if the tag is still valid or not?

Answer (score 6):

While I agree with the other answers, I don't agree w3schools is a good source for...well, anything really.  Look to the specification itself when looking for data:

[The HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER):

> The CENTER element is exactly equivalent to specifying the [DIV](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-DIV) element with the [align](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#adef-align) attribute set to "center". **The [CENTER](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER) element is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/conform.html#deprecated)**.

Is it still *valid*? Nope (but it *works*, that's a different question), it's been deprecated since HTML4 - semantically it's just not inline with other elements.

Comment: I am not the downvoter... :) .. but I don't get one argument of your answer  "Is it still valid? Nope (but it works, that's a different question)", I don't get it... what you call valid? At the same time you say it is deprecated, but a deprecated "element" is the one signed to be avoided, not that it is "invalid"

Comment: @Diego - I said it's *not* valid "Is it still valid? No"...am I looking over some obvious omission above? apologies if it's not clear, let me know what would be clearer.

Comment: I think my comment was the one not clear.. what's the difference from being valid to working? Deprecated means a suggestion not to use because it should/will be removed on future versions, right? So, if it is deprecated on a version.. this means it still works and is valid on that version

Comment: @Diego - Let me put it a different way, it's not *valid*, as in run it through a validator: http://validator.w3.org/  - [like this](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://fiddle.jshell.net/nick_craver/ZFbh3/show/light/) and you'll see it's not *valid*.  It does however work, as defined in the [W3C definition of deprecated elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/conform.html#deprecated): "User agents should continue to support deprecated elements for reasons of backward compatibility."  ...so yes it works, and it should *work*, bit it's not *valid*, is that a bit clearer?

Comment: Ok! .. So, according to this "definition of valid" and using w3 validator, I would say that <center> is not valid on html5 (as it is clearly not!) and on html 4 strict. But valid on html 4 "not strict", right?

Comment: @Diego - correct, it's valid in HTML 4.01 Transitional - [you can try it out here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://fiddle.jshell.net/nick_craver/ZFbh3/show/light/&doctype=HTML+4.01+Transitional).

Comment: @Nick - interesting point on the definitions of deprecated and obsolete. HTML5 turns this around. No markup is marked "Deprecated" in HTML5 because there is a general assumption (whatever the W3C says) that "deprecated" means "support may be removed in the future". Instead markup can be denoted "obsolete", but it's fully accepted that support for that markup cannot ever be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Valid? As in "this is W3C valid markup"? **Yes**. (Albeit deprecated).

Should you use it? No. The `<center>` tag has no semantic meaning in a web page, and is a styling element *par excellence*. Use proper CSS alignment and positioning to style your web pages.

For text aligning use `text-align: center;`.

For element positioning use auto-width margins: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`